# Attach Log4net log file in Output attachment of Coded UI test

Tags: c#, selenium, log4net, coded-ui-tests

I have a coded UI test in which I am generating a result SleniumLog.html file using log4net and I want to attach that file to the Attachment of the output of executed test result.
As you can see in the screenshot below there is a UITestActionlog.html present and I want to attach one more file here which is present in 'Out' directory of the result.

Is it possible to do that?

[image]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/33708155/546871

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I attach an image to TRX (Test Result Reported) File?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33696792/how-can-i-attach-an-image-to-trx-test-result-reported-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [TestContext.AddResultFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testcontext.addresultfile.aspx) method.